# Javascript Closure or assignment operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var xu = 12;

var f = function () {
  var b = xu;
  return function() {
    console.log(b);
  }
}
```

The invocation `f()()` gives `12` on console.

Then I write the following statements.

```
xu = 14; 
f()();
```

As per my knowledge, function invocation should print `12`. We are not changing the value of `b` anywhere.

But the output is `14`. Does it mean that assignment operator is passing the reference of the variable and not just the value?

*Edit:* Again, but if I use no closures, assignment operator does not assign the reference. Confused!

Comment: How about tell us what you're trying to do instead of asking about that specific piece of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the below code can explain:

```
var xu = 12;

var f = function () {
  var b = xu;
  return function() {
    console.log(b);
  }
}

b = f()
b(); // 12
xu =14
b() // 12
f()() // 14
```

`f()() // 14` you are again invoking the function and it will get the current value in `xu`. Were as `b() // 12` you have the old value binded via closure

Answer (score 2):

Well when you run `f()` it reassigns `b` to the value of `xu` each time

Comment: var py = 1;
var a = py;
py = 2;
console.log(a); // 1

Why, then?

Comment: Because JavaScript Numbers are assigned by value, not by reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `f()`, you re-assign `b` to `xu`. Unless you do it like this,

var xu = 12;

```
var f = function () {
  var b = xu;
  return function() {
    console.log(b);
  }
}

f()(); // prints '12'

var c = f();
xu = 13;

c(); // prints '12'

f()(); // prints '13'
```